# Expiring a document db record at a set time

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to expire a document db record at a specific time e.g. every day at 1 am?

I know that there is the Time to Live feature but that is relative to the time the record was last updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TTL is your only automated option for expiring a document. If you want documents to expire at a specific time, you'll need to compute the timespan yourself  and set TTL (in *seconds*) accordingly for each document.

Alternatively, you can create a scheduled task that you execute at a particular time every day, to clean out data.

Comment: Thanks David for your answer